# Thousands, hundreds, tens and units?

Tags: word-request

- thousands of messages
- hundreds of messages
- tens of messages
- units of messages????

I searched CZ=>EN dictionaries and they offer me word unit but in different meaning. Is it appropriate to use "units" for amount classification below ten?

Comment: I've never heard "units" used to refer to a large number of something .

Comment: ***units*** is completely non-idiomatic in your context. Also note that whereas ***dozens*** (or even ***scores*** for older speakers) is perfectly common, many speakers don't like ***tens*** in such contexts, so my advice would be to avoid it.

Comment: I thought so. Which word can classify 1-9 digits?

Comment: Just "messages". Several messages. A few messages. Less than ten messages, for example.

Comment: I used "Up to ten messages"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idiomatically, we don't<sup>1</sup> often use ***tens*** [of X] as a quantifier / determiner, but ***dozens*** (12's) and ***scores*** (20's) cover much the same numeric range (note that ***scores*** is gradually falling into disuse).

[image]

And we *certainly* don't use ***units*** in any such contexts. For single-digit and low two-digit approximations, we have ***a couple, a few*** for values nearer the lower end, and ***quite a few, several*** for the higher end. But these are *very* imprecise terms.

---

<sup>1</sup> But we *do* refer to ***tens of thousands*** and ***tens of millions*** in many contexts where we feel it's relevant that large imprecise numbers should be accurate to an "order of magnitude" (within a power of ten).

Answer (score -1):

We use "hundreds" to indicate that there's more than one hundred. If you want to say there's more than one, then the use of the plural already says that.